# Using service worker over web VPN

Tags: angular, ssl, proxy, service-worker, vpn

I've got a bit of a strange problem with a site I've created in Angular that uses a service worker.  When accessed normally everything is fine, however due to some slightly convoluted customer requirements, one of our customers needs to access the site over a clientless web VPN.  Basically this means they go to our Fortigate VPN site, log in, and then click a bookmark to get to the Angular site with service worker.

The problem however is that the VPN changes the URL, so something like www.mysite.com becomes www.my-vpn.com/proxy/https/www.mysite.com.

This means when someone visits the site it tries to load the service worker from www.my-vpn.com/ngsw-config rather than www.mysite.com/ngsw-config, and everything breaks (not surprisingly).

My question is - is it possible to get this setup working, so that my Angular app works correctly over the new route? And if not, are there alternatives that would not require a client based VPN solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Cisco has bug fix for this issue, check this url
https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCvj41748

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.  It requires a login though and looks like their create account process is broken as it won't let me sign in.  Any chance of a summary? I'm a little confused as to why a Cisco bug would affect a Fortigate product?